# Electric circuit on presentation

Tags: circuitikz, draw

I am working on presentation and I searched for best way to draw electrical circuits and found out it is in `LaTeX`. I worked a little bit in `LaTeX`, but not enough to draw these, so if there is anyone who would help me I would be very grateful. BTW, I need to recreate these circuits:

[image: Second]
[image: First]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  See the `circuitikz` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz

Comment: For the logic circuit you can start from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583841/how-can-i-make-my-logic-circuits-look-better, for the other you can for example look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540785/full-wave-rectifier-circuit

Comment: Another suggestion, if you do not want to go the LaTeX way (meaning that you have to learn both Ti*k*Z and LaTeX, so a quite nice inversion of time must be taken into account) I would suggest circuit (http://opencircuitdesign.com/xcircuit/) which also is able to produce really nice circuits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Here's the first circuit, I'll leave the second as an exercise for the reader :).

```
\documentclass[border=20, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) to[L, l=\(L_1\)] (0, 4);
        \draw (2, 0) to[C, l=\(C_1\), *-*] (2, 4);
        \draw (2, 4) to[R, l=\(R_1\), *-*] (4, 4);
        \draw (4, 0) to[C, l=\(C_2\), *-*] (4, 4);
        \draw (6, 0) to[R, l=\(R_2\), *-] (6, 2);
        \draw[fill=black] (6, 2) to[diode, l=\(D_1\), -*] (6, 4);
        \draw (8, 0) to[R, l=\(R_3\), *-] (8, 2);
        \draw[fill=black] (8, 4) to[diode, l=\(D_2\), *-] (8, 2);
        \node[op amp, xscale=-1, yscale=-1] (opamp) at (14, 2) {};
        \draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 0)$) to[short, *-] (opamp.out);
        \draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 0)$) -- ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 1.5)$);
        \draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 0)$) -- ($(opamp.out) + (-1, -1.5)$);
        \coordinate (opamp plus) at (opamp.+);
        \coordinate (opamp minus) at (opamp.-);  %  - sign in opamp.- causes errors with the |- notation
        \draw (opamp plus) -- (opamp plus|-(0, 3.5));
        \draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 1.5)$) to[R, n=R4, -*] (opamp plus|-(0, 3.5));
        \node[below] at (R4.s) {\(R_4\)};  % want name to appear below below
        \draw (opamp minus) -- (opamp minus|-(0, 0.5));
        \draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, -1.5)$) to[R, l=\(R_5\), -*] (opamp minus|-(0, 0.5));
        \draw (0, 4) -- (2, 4);
        \draw (4, 4) -- (opamp plus|-(0, 4));
        \draw (15.2, 4) -- (opamp plus);
        \draw (0, 0) -- (8, 0);
        \draw (8, 0) to[R, l=\(R_6\)] (opamp minus|-(0, 0));
        \draw (15.2, 0) -- (opamp minus);
        \node[ground] at (8, 0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks guys you helped me a lot!!!

Comment: Nice. Can you elaborate why you say `%  - sign in opamp.- causes errors with the |- notation` ? Normally adding a space solves the problem, but I am not sure...

Comment: You could very well be right that adding a space fixes it, aliasing the mode was just the first solution I thought of